# How to replace a div with another div and making it solid in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, input

I am trying to replace a div with another div when a button is clicked because I want to replace the input area with the results area. When I hide the input section and replace it with the results, then everything else gets messed up because it acts like the results section is not there and other elements overlap it. Is there a way to make the results section a solid element so nothing can overlap it?

Thanks

```
<div class="mainSection">
 <div class="inputArea" id="inputArea">Input</div>
 <div class="resultsArea" id="resultsArea">Results</div>
 <button onclick="showResults()" id="button">Show</button>
 <img src="image.png"> /* this image overlaps the results */
</div>
```

```
    .mainSection {
    width: 900px;
    height: 900px;
    border: 9px;
    }
    .inputArea {
    display: block;
    }
    .resultsArea {
    display: none;
    }
```

```
function showResults() {
  document.getElementById("inputArea").style.display="none";
  document.getElementById("button").style.display="none";
  document.getElementById("resultsArea").style.display="block";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- `display:none` means that the tag in question will
  not appear on the page at all
- `visibility:hidden` means that the tag in question will
  not appear on the page but it will still take space

```
function showResults() {
  document.getElementById("inputArea").style.visibility="hidden";
  document.getElementById("button").style.visibility="hidden";
  document.getElementById("resultsArea").style.display="block";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use one div and change the innerHtml of it

```js
function showResults() {
  document.getElementById("inputArea").innerHtml = `
  Here type the html you wont
  `;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it where the innerHTML is an id that already exists on the page like this: function showResults() {
        document.getElementById("inputSection").innerHtml = document.getElementById('resultsSection');
        }